# Segmentation Fault, large arrays

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 1024
int main(){
  int i, j;
  int a[N][N];
  int b[N][N];
  for (i=0;i<N;i++){
    a[i][i]=i;
    b[i][i]=i;
  }
  for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
         printf("%d", a[i][j]);
         printf("%d", b[i][j]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

This program is a reason of segmentation fault, but if I define N as 1023, program will work correctly. Why it happens?

Comment: AurelioDeRosa, it's only example, in my program I encountered with similar problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are overflowing the stack. `2 * 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(int)` is a lot for most systems.

The simplest solution would be to make the arrays `static`.

```
static int a[N][N];
static int b[N][N];
```

Other methods:

- Make the arrays global (this is essentially the same as the above)
- Use `malloc` in a loop and of course remember to `free`

  ```
  int **a = malloc(N * sizeof *a);
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      a[i] = malloc(N * sizeof *a[i]);
  ```

Comment: @AlexeyMatveev OR you can tell the compiler to give you a bigger stack! There is an option for that!

Comment: @xanatos: it's not necessarily up to the compiler - in many environments stack size is determined at run-time

Comment: @xanatos Picking up where @PaulR left, for instance on Unix this is set using `ulimit -s`.

Comment: static int p[20000000]; causes the following error: variable length array declaration can not have 'static' storage duration. How is this different from the suggestion?

Comment: @Michal No it won't. That error will arise when you use `static` for a [Variable Length Array](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).