# Why does g++ show segmentation fault on declaration of large arrays when declared locally in functions while it works fine when declared globally?

Tags: c++

I wanted to declare 4 2-D arrays of size 1000*1000(4*10^6*4 bytes considering int) . Initially, when I declared these arrays in main() function, I was getting segmentation fault.

Later I declared the arrays globally and the program worked fine. Why this is so??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, a place where you can ask questions about *stack overflows*, which is what you got.

Comment: (and please tag your questions with the language you're using)

Comment: @Mat Shame that question and its answers are terrible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: well, there's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902228/segmentation-fault-large-arrays?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029671/declare-large-array-on-stack is actually more useful in terms of answers for C++

Comment: One question that is added by the OP is "Why does not it segfault also when the arrays are declared as global variable?".

@vinit I suggest that you edit your question post, to show two small programs showing the behavior you describe: one that segfaults, and one that does not.

Comment: None of the dups even mention static storage duration, even though that's 50% of this question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: want to re-open this then?

Comment: @Mat I also agree that the pointed duplicate question does not answer all the question of the OP. That is not a perfect duplicate. I am not a moderator, but as far as I understand the question should be reopened.

Comment: @lrineau: I already voted to reopen, I hadn't really taken that into account when voting to close. (Ping'd Lightness in case they wanted to do the same)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: should not the question be reopened?

Comment: @Mat: for user who cannot vote open/close, which flag is adapted to ask for reopening?

Comment: @lrineau: there's no pre-made flag for that, you need to chose the "other" reason and explain what you'd like

Comment: @Irineau: Yeah I think so. We can always re-close if we find a better duplicate.

Comment: @Irineau: Thanks for your efforts to reopen the question. I am really obliged :) .

Comment: @vinit: In StackOverflow, the self answer should be formatted differently. Please create an official answer to your question, and remove the answer from the question. After a few hours, you will be able to self-accept your own answer, to mark the question as closed.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When large arrays are declared inside a function, they are stored on the **stack frame**, whose size is not much(don't know the exact value).

While when the array is declared globally, it is stored in **Data** (if the variable is initialized) and in **bss** (if not initialized). The size of Data and bss is very high(don't know the exact value), that is why they could accommodate large array declarations.

Comment: AFAIK most Compilers let you obtain 2MB for a single stack frame.